# Laravel queued mail not received

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, swiftmailer

I'm trying to use queue for my email sending on Laravel 5.4

```
Mail::to('email@example.com')->queue(new NotifyCustomer($client));
```

What works: QUEUE_DRIVER=sqs or database with Mailgun

What works: QUEUE_DRIVER=sync with domain up******.com

What doesn't work: QUEUE_DRIVER=sqs or database with domain up******.com. But, it works for other domains.

Is this an issue with domain up******.com MX entry or DNS setup or something not working at Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable?

**Additional:**
Looking into the code of Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable, it is executing Mailable::send() as well. I wonder what is the difference between the direct and queued send approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very likely a DNS issue with the hosts of your domain. Your ip may be blacklisted by the host, I would suggest contacting them to check for certain.

Comment: If there was a blacklist, I'm sure the sync approach would not work as well no?

Comment: Just to update here. I discovered that the cause of the problem could be the Laravel scheduling. I stopped the queue worker from working and tried out to process the queued mails (table 'jobs') using my own wrapper. When I manually trigger them by browser, the emails were received. However, when I tried to incorporate Laravel scheduling (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling) to process the queue, the queued mail jobs were processed (captured in Events\MessageSending) but the emails were not received. So, I have to resort to the server's cronjob to send out the mails for now.